# PHP Proxy without cURL

Tags: proxy, php

The next 2 weeks I'll be watching the house for my parents.
But before I went here, I forgot to forward ports in the router.
I do have a kind of access. I can place files on my webserver.

But I need SSH on my NAS and the port isn't forwarded.
So I'm looking for a PHP Web Proxy that doesn't use cURL and works "out of the box". 
I've tried some different scripts with no luck. They're either outdated or missing some code.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a web proxy that works "out of the box" and can access 192.168.1.1 and supports cookies?
It would be greatly appreciated.